Why does setting `umask` to `0077` (and then downloading public key) makes a gpg public key unavailable for apt?
Why does setting umask to 0077 makes a gpg public key unavailable for apt when installing a package, e.g.
umask 0077
curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg
  echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/ stable main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-beta.list
apt update
apt install brave-browser-beta
  

The above does not work, I get this output:
Err:4 https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0B31DBA06A8A26F9
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0B31DBA06A8A26F9
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.



This does work:
umask 0022
curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg
  echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/ stable main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-beta.list
apt update
apt install brave-browser-beta

Why does setting umask to 0077 (and then downloading public key) makes a gpg public key unavailable for apt? The key was downloaded as root, and so was executed apt update, why then this issue?

apt runs download-related operations using a sandbox user by default, _apt. I can’t check right now, but it’s possible that apt update key verification is done using this user too, which would mean the keys have to be readable by the _apt user.
See Why are directory permissions preventing "sudo apt install" using a file? for a similar problem.
